# VB.NET Plugin Architecture

Tags: vb.net

Hello I'm working on using the interface class in vb.net to make a plugin architecture. So far I've not found a step by step tutorial for a beginner. But I've gotten as far as this:

**Main App**

```
Public Class PluginHandler

Interface IApplications
    Sub ChangeForms()
End Interface

Public Shared Sub GetDLLFromDir(ByVal TheDir)
    For Each dll As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(TheDir, "*.dll")
        LoadPlugin(dll)
    Next
End Sub

Public Shared Sub LoadPlugin(ByVal ThePlugin)
    Dim Asm = Assembly.LoadFile(ThePlugin)
    Dim type As Type = Asm.GetType("TestPlugin.Class_TestPlugin")
    Dim method As MethodInfo = type.GetMethod("ChangeForms")
    method.Invoke(Nothing, Nothing)
End Sub

End Class
```

**TestPlugin.vb**

```
Public Class Class_TestPlugin
Implements Plugin_Application.PluginHandler.IApplications

Sub ChangeForms() Implements Plugin_Application. _
PluginHandler.IApplications.ChangeForms

    Dim NewForm As New Form_Test
    NewForm.Show()

End Sub
End Class
```

My issue is it says for the method to invoke --> Non-static method requires a target.
I seen on another forum that the method may not be found. I found it says the methods name and void. But I'm not sure what to do. If somebody can mod my code to work or give me some ideas to make my code work. Thanks :)

Here is a link to my test project folder: [Link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26523776/Projects.7z)

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? You should take a look at the Managed Extensibility Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an object the method should be called on:

```
Dim ctor = type.GetConstructor({}) 'no parameters for constructor
Dim obj = ctor.Invoke({})
method.Invoke(obj, {})
```